# Some old icons are still showing

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, chat

In the [Hot Network Questions](http://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot), the old icon is still shown.

In addition, in Chat, the old icon is shown on the user card as well.

[image]

Comment: it's probably cache issue & it will be fixed, no worries.

Comment: Caching. Always blame it on the caching. Or the monkey.

Comment: Sinilar problem on the Android app

Comment: Let's just all wait for a day before reporting these kinds of issues.

Comment: And wait at least 2 days before blaming monkeys.

Comment: @Jamal, this is only "completed" for the chat user icons. In the HNQ the old icon is still shown.

Comment: @Heslacher: Strange.  I can see the new icon now there as well.

Comment: On the page following the link above ? I just did a hard refresh and still the old ones are showing.